# Separate data in Column and rows, and link to value

Tags: excel, vba, split, multiple-columns, rows

As you can see in this excel example, column A has mixed data.

[image: Example of mixed data]

The bold M numbers are the "keys" and the blue text that is indented and blue is linked to it. I'm trying to figure out how to separate the blue text from the bold M numbers but keep them linked as I am trying to insert this data into a SQL database.

So for example, this is the output I am trying to get to, so I can insert it into my database table.

[image: Example of separated data]

I've tried doing text to column, but I am having an issue linking them to the appropriate bold number. I'm thinking this is in call for excel-vba, but I don't know where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need VBA.  If the BOLD values will always start with "M" then do the following:

```
B1: =A1
B2: =IF(LEFT(A2,1)="M",A2,B1)
C1: =IF(LEFT(A1,1)="M","",A1)
```

The result will have columns B and C populated with the data as you need.

Comment: That is awesome, thank you so much, I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and this worked like a charm. Thank you so much, greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, `LEFT(A2)` works in the same way as `LEFT(A2,1)`

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you need `VBA`, you may go for something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rngCell         As Range

    Dim colBold         As New Collection
    Dim colNormal       As New Collection
    Dim colTimes        As New Collection

    Dim varMy           As Variant
    Dim lngCounter      As Long
    Dim lngSum          As Long
    Dim lngCur          As Long
    Dim lngBoldCounter  As Long
    Dim lngMax          As Long
    Dim rngMyRange      As Range

    Set rngMyRange = Range("A1:A20")

    For Each rngCell In rngMyRange
        If rngCell.Font.Bold Then
            colTimes.Add lngSum
            colBold.Add rngCell
            lngCounter = 0
        Else
            lngSum = lngSum + 1
            lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
            colNormal.Add rngCell
        End If
    Next rngCell

    lngCounter = 1
    lngSum = 0
    lngBoldCounter = 1

    lngMax = colBold.Count + 1
    rngMyRange.Offset(, 4).Clear
    rngMyRange.Offset(, 5).Clear

    For Each varMy In colNormal

        Cells(lngCounter, 5) = varMy
        Cells(lngCounter, 6) = colBold(lngBoldCounter)

        If lngCounter < colNormal.Count Then
            If colTimes(lngBoldCounter + 1) <= lngCounter Then
                lngBoldCounter = lngBoldCounter + 1
                If lngBoldCounter = lngMax Then
                    lngBoldCounter = lngBoldCounter - 1
                    Debug.Print varMy.Address
                End If
            End If
        End If

        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    Next varMy

End Sub
```

The code is not optimal as I have made it on the go, but it takes the bold into account and produces the columns 5 and 6, concerning them.

[image]